# Multiple edit suggestion approvals on same question by same user in quick succession

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

The same user has been able to do three different suggested edit approvals on the same answer in the space of 5 minutes. Not only that, two of the suggested edits came from the same user (different to the approver). Here is a screenshot*:

[image]

And for convenience, here are the links to the edits, in chronological order: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/791875), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/791876), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/791883).

As you can see from the image this is not the only user who is doing this. This might be by design, but if so I think it is a bad design.

- Why can one user make two small suggested edits to the same answer in the space of a couple of minutes?
- Why can one user review edits on the same question three times in the space of five minutes?

This sort of thing is annoying me a lot. To me this smells like people taking the piss, gaming the system, having a laugh at the expense of good reviewers who try to do a decent job. It shows me there are people out there who cannot be trusted with reviews - is it time to raise the reputation threshold for reviewing suggested edits? Or is it time to develop a new anti-gaming script to identify this sort of thing?

*sorry about the lack of freehand circles. Issues with dodgy review queue actions have left me capable of only doing stright lines at the moment.

Comment: Review monkeys, spoiling the fun for everyone... <sigh>

Comment: [One of the edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/791876) says "Fixed grammer" in its description. *shudders*

Comment: @Null: every second edit I get to review says something about "grammer" or "gramma" or "grandma" in its description.

Comment: I get frustrated by the suggested edit queue myself.  Too often, I reject an edit and get the "this edit has already been approved" message.  If you want to get credit for the review, you have to hit approve (or reject) fast, but if you do that, you don't leave time to properly review the question.