# StackOverflow helps regulating the addicted users. Really?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, addiction

[There's an simplified Chinese article](http://www.huxiu.com/article/34968/1.html)  at June 4 this year (not April 1 !) said :

> StackOverflow会对**上瘾的人**关闭特定功能，以限制他们的使用

which means

> StackOverflow regulates **addicted users** by restricting their actions
> specifically.

**Is that true?**

I know it helps if SO could ban me from the reviewer queue periodically.

---

### Edit:

Thanks to @euphoria overlord, the original article is from [**TechCrunch**](http://techcrunch.com/2014/05/31/is-some-tech-too-addictive/) :

> StackOverflow, the world’s largest technical question and answer site,
> deprecates certain features to limit use

And here is the whole paragraph:

> In fact, some companies have already started limiting certain features
> to people who overuse their sites. StackOverflow, the world’s largest
> technical question and answer site, deprecates certain features to
> limit use. Jeff Atwood, the company’s co-founder, says the system was
> designed to not only improve the quality of content on the site but
> also to protect susceptible users. “Programmers should be out there in
> the world creating things too,” Atwood writes, making the point that
> he wants StackOverflow to be a utility, not a mindless distraction.

Comment: Funny thing. This article you linked is direct copy of the following link from TechCrunch http://techcrunch.com/2014/05/31/is-some-tech-too-addictive/

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the original one. My link is actually a translated article but it didn't provide the source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [TechCrunch article](http://techcrunch.com/2014/05/31/is-some-tech-too-addictive/) that the Chinese page you linked to links to the following point [from Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again/136060#136060):

> > a user who dives straight into the community and contributes left,
> >     right and centre will still be forced to wait for privileges (and
> >     general recognition via rep)
>
> This is intentional, and by design.
>
> Regardless of how talented one may or may not be, they cannot waltz
>   into a brand new community and hope to absorb its norms, behaviors,
>   and culture in a single day. Or even a week!
>
> The current system is designed to reward continued participation, but
>   not to the point that it creates obsession. Programmers should be out
>   there in the world creating things, too. The rep cap requires that you
>   come back to our community over a fairly significant period of time,
>   and contribute regularly during that time.
>
> I think it's also fair that users who contribute one really brilliant
>   bit of wisdom or insight continue to get rep for that over time.
>   Otherwise we're rewarding quantity over quality.
>
> Most crucially, if users want to exceed the +200 rep cap per day,
>   there is already a way to do so: play the expert game of striving for
>   accepted answers (immune to cap) and earning answer bounties (immune
>   to cap).
>
> "If you love someone, set them free."

So no, you can't get banned unless you start [churning out low-quality reviews like crazy, see this.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150039/multiple-edit-suggestion-approvals-on-same-question-by-same-user-in-quick-succes)    What the limit is is actually the 200 rep/day limit all sites have.

So in short, it's not as exaggerated as the article makes it sound, the only thing inhibiting you is the 200 rep/day limit, and even that, as Jeff points out, doesn't factor in accepted answers or awarded bounties.

Comment: I am thinking the same way. It seems the author over-interpreted what Jeff said.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the vote and flag limits per day, but these are mostly to prevent abuse by bots, rather than addicts.